# How to test Safari extension's popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, safari-extension

I want to test a safari extension that I'm currently working on. The extension is not packed and already loaded in safari.

In chrome I can easily access the popup html page by going to:

> chrome-extension://EXTENSION_ID/popup.html

But in safari, it looks like this:

> safari-extension://com.company.stuff-extension-DEVELOPER_ID/1r0c2t2/html/popup.html

Where `1r0c2t2` is a random (?) string that changes on every browser load.

So my question is, how can I get that random string?

I'm using safari 10 (native safaridriver) and selenium-webdriver v3.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no support in safaridriver for testing extensions. Please file an enhancement request with your use cases at https://bugreport.apple.com/